# How to get Visual Studio performance tools to load symbols for "System.Core.ni.dll"

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 11's profiler (sampling), and am having trouble getting the report to show me the code I need it to.  The problem is that several of the assemblies won't load because they're "Native Images".  The primary one I'm concerned about is "System.Core.ni.dll".  Because that symbol isn't loading, when I go to view the report I can't see why my Expression is slow.  Instead, it just bundles all of the samples related to Expressions into a line reading "System.Core.ni.dll".

If I look at the Output window, I see the following two lines:

Failed to load symbols for C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System.Core\713a8c0e41e664d349efcc0cec7f5e86\System.Core.ni.dll
Loaded symbols for C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll

Notice how the first symbol doesn't load?

What are my options?  Can I stop native images from being used?  Can I load the symbols for native images?

Answer (score 30):

I had a similar problem on Windows 8 and found a post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/10/creating-ngen-pdbs-for-profiling-reports.aspx) that helped me solve the problem.  Don't know if it will solve the OP's issue but it worked for me.

Comment: Great answer. Works for Ngen dlls (*.ni.dll).

Comment: This helped me on Windows 7.

Comment: This helped me on Windows 10.

Comment: ...And this is why link-only answers are bad.  Link is dead.

Comment: Seven year old answer and the most useful follow-up comment was yesterday!  I have the same issue as the OP, and I came here seeking answers.  Too bad the link is dead ==> "404 - Page not found ".  However, this appears to be the intended (previously working) link:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/creating-ngen-pdbs-for-profiling-reports/